# Изменение размеров окна при FormBorderStyle: None в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

В общем, создал форму, в свойствах формы `FormBorderStyle` указал `None`, чтобы не было рамки окна и заголовка. Собственно, вопрос: как теперь сделать так, чтобы можно было изменять размер окна (растягивать и сужать), не имея при этом заголовка окна и рамочки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, вас устроит следующее решение:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x40000;

            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.Style |= WS_SIZEBOX;

            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, у формы без заголовка будет тонкая рамочка, за которую можно менять её размеры.

Comment: Ваш ответ очень помог, но есть небольшая проблема, вверху появляется белая полоса, как от нее избавиться или хотя бы поменять ее цвет?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел кое-что...предлагают в правый в угол формы поставить небольшого размера `pictureBox` или `panel` сделать их невидимыми, а на событие `MouseMove()` повесить изменение размеров. Например:

```
private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(this.PointToClient(MousePosition).X, this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y);
    }
}
```

Также установите у `panel` свойство `Anchor` в `Bottom, Right`, чтобы изменение срабатывало только на нижней и правой границе `panel`.

Оригинал ответа:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6e5c1da4-b535-4226-b7c8-c6cef2c0c21f/resizing-moving-formborderstylenone-form?forum=vblanguage

Comment: ну вариант так себе, мне нужно изменять размер окна не только "тягая за углы", а как и в обычной форме, за любое место на краю. Такое не подскажите как сделать?